# Monte Carlo Simulation to estimating pi using circle

Tags: python, algorithm

I have a question on the algorithm below. What confused me is why `x = random.random()*2 -1` and `y = random.random()*2 -1` rather than just simply `x = random.random()` and `y = random.random()`? The complete code is as following:

```
import random

NUMBER_OF_TRIALS= 1000000
numberOfHits = 0

for i in range(NUMBER_OF_TRIALS):
    x = random.random()*2 -1
    y = random.random()*2 -1

    if x * x + y * y <=1:
         numberOfHits +=1
pi = 4* numberOfHits / NUMBER_OF_TRIALS

print("PI is", pi)
```

Comment: To make the range from -1 to 1 instead of 0 to 1.

Comment: `random.random()` returns a number between 0 and 1. Multiply by 2 to get a number between 0 and 2. Subtract 1 to get a number between -1 and 1

Comment: The title has nothing to do with your question. Please consider changing.

Comment: You're shooting darts at a unit circle.  The circumscribing square is over the range [-1, 1].

Comment: As others said, that is to cover the area of the whole circle, but then again, I see no reason to cover the whole circle. You could work on the first quadrant only if you had just `random()`. So, I think both should work.

Comment: if I see it right it should be just `Random()` as you are multiplying by `4*` at the end (that represents just single quadrant of the unit circle). As others suggested the lines you are asking about create uniform distribution for all quadrants so in that case you should remove the `4*` from the result

Answer (score 4):

The circle in this simulation is centered at (0, 0) with a radius of 1, so

```
x = random.random() * 2 - 1
y = random.random() * 2 - 1
```

will make the range for each -1 to 1.

Answer (score 3):

The interesting thing about this question is that the implementation works just as well, and gives you the same expected answer whether you use `random.random()` or `random.random()*2-1`...  so the reason why the author chose to use `random.random()*2-1` has nothing to do with what the program does.

The *author* of this code understands the algorithm as follows:

- Imagine a circle inscribe in a square.  Use the unit circle because it's simplest
- Choose random points within the square, and see how many are also inside the circle
- The circle has area pi and the square has area 4, so the proportion of points that fall in the circle will approach pi/4.  Calculate the measured ratio and solve for pi.

Now, the square in which the unit circle is inscribed goes from (-1,-1) to (1,1).  Since `random()` only gives you a number in [0,1), it needs to be multiplied by two and shifted to select a random number in [-1,1), which chooses random points within the square.

If the author had used `random()`, then he would be selecting point within the first quadrant only.  All the quadrants look exactly the same, so the ratio of hits to misses would be the same and the program would still work just fine, but then the program would *not* be implementing the above-described procedure, and would be more difficult to understand.

One of the most important properties of good code is that it clearly communicates the author's intent.

Answer (score 1):

`random()` gives you a random float between 0 and 1.

`random()*2 -1` gives you a random float between -1 and +1.

The algorithm, as usually explained, is in terms of the proportion of points in the unit square that are in the unit circle being `pi/4`, which is obvious after a moment's thought, and the second one gives you that directly.

It doesn't take *much* additional thought to see that using only the upper-right quadrant of the unit square and the unit circle will still give you `pi/4` (although it is possible to confuse yourself and get it wrong, as I embarrassingly did in the first version of this answer). But it's not as blindingly obvious. And that might be a good enough reason for a tutorial to not do things that way.

If you were interested in calculating `pi` as efficiently as possible, it would probably make more sense to just use `random()`, and add a comment about how you're diving both the unit square and the unit circle by the same value so the odds are still `pi/4`. But if you're interested in showing novice programmers how to design and implement randomized algorithms? Probably better to write it the way it's written.

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding your point, I don't think this is true. The probability of a random point in the unit square falling in that circle quadrant is still `pi`. It makes sense because adding the other four quandants just adds identical probabilities. And…I just ran it in python and confirmed, it converges on `pi` not `2pi` with `x` and `y` equal to `random.random()`.

Comment: @MarkMeyer Oops, you're right; I overcomplicated things and did the math wrong in my head. The probability is of course `pi/4`, not `pi`, for the whole unit square. But for the quadrant, yeah, the two `sqrt(4)`s cancel out, so it's still the same `pi/4`, so the same `4 * numberOfHits / NUMBER_OF_TRIALS` works without changes…